# Determine Excel 2007 addin vs excel 2010 addin

Tags: vsto

﻿I have received a MS Excel addin project build in VS2010. How do I determine whether it is Excel 2007 addin or Excel 2010 addin project ?

Answer (score 2):

Technically, the answer of Mitja is correct. In practice, this is not entirely accurate. As far as I know, this can only be checked by running add-in in Excel 2007 and 2010. Most likely, it will work in both cases. Checking of the version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly does not help, as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 12.0 works fine in Excel 2007 and 2010 (and even 2013) and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 14.0 - too. In most cases, the add-in itself will also work equally in all three versions of Excel (2007, 2010 & 2013)
The only significant difference - a version of Excel that runs when debugging - you can see in your .сsproj - file:

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties [...] OfficeVersion="12.0" [...] DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Excel\InstallRoot\Path#excel.exe" />
      </FlavorProperties>
      [...]
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check references that are added to the project. Not sure what kinda of Addin it is, but I'll assume it is using Interop assemblies. Then you can check the version on the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly. If it is 12.0.0.0 it is targeting Excel 2007, version 14.0.0.0 would mean it is Excel 2010.